Why can’t FFprobe get an APNG’s duration?
When I try to use FFprobe to get APNG’s duration like this:
ffprobe ./test.apng

which the test.apng can play normally.  after the command, I got:
Input #0, apng, from './test.apng':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Video: apng, rgba(pc), 100x100, 13.33 fps, 13.33 tbr, 100k tbn

The duration field is N/A. Does FFprobe not support APNG completely? Or is there some other method to achieve this?
